# How to create an html tag above others in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm attempting to make this thing where, when you press a button, it'll add a line of text to a scroll-able div. However, every time I press the button, the new paragraph appears below the last one, when I want it to appear **above** the last one.
I've got this down so far:

```js
function addToLog(user, action) {
  // Setting up local variables
  var newEntry = document.createElement("p");
  var entryText;
  var battleLog = document.getElementById("log");

  // Applying style
  newEntry.style.color = "black";
  newEntry.style.margin = 0;

  // Checking possible inputs
  if (user === 'player' && action === 'attack') {
    entryText = document.createTextNode("Player attacked the enemy for some damage!");
  } else {
    entryText = document.createTextNode("Error");
  }

  // Placing text into log
  newEntry.appendChild(entryText);
  battleLog.appendChild(newEntry);
};
```

```css
#log {
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 300px;
  width: 900px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#attack:hover {
  color: red;
}
.button {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 16px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.button:hover {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="attack" ; class="button" onClick="addToLog('player','attack')">Attack</div>
  <!-- Displaying action log -->
  <div id="log"></div>
  <!-- Starting game script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" ; src="gameScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I ended up copy-pasting parts of my current project into here, so it might look messy.
As you can see, when you click the attack button, the text appears in the action log. However, every new paragraph appears at the very bottom of the action log, when I want it to appear at the top. Is there any way to put every new paragraph at the very top?
Sorry if I'm missing something here, I've tried searching everything I could before asking about this myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://callmenick.com/post/prepend-child-javascript take a look at this

Answer (score 0):

try using [insertBefore()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp) instead of [appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: Could you clarify that for me? Where should I be putting insertBefore()?